# ReactJS + react-router. Изменение render'а одного компонента через другого

Tags: reactjs

Есть компонент App, который отрисовывает меню в зависимости от того, авторизован пользователь или нет

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {session: []}
}

componentDidMount() {
    $.post('authenticate', (session) => {
        this.setState({session: [session, ...this.state.session]})
        if (!session.authorized) browserHistory.push('/auth')
    })
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

}

render() {
    const nav = this.state.session.map((param, index) => {
        if (param.authorized) {
            return (
                <ul key={index} className="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><Link activeClassName='active-link' to='/home'>Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link activeClassName='active-link' to='/users'>Users</Link></li>
                    <li><Link activeClassName='active-link' to='/chat'>Chat</Link></li>
                    <li><Link activeClassName='active-link' to='/logout'>Log out</Link></li>
                </ul>
            )
        }

        return (
            <ul key={index} className="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><Link activeClassName='active-link' to='/home'>Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link activeClassName='active-link' to='/registration'>Registration</Link></li>
            </ul>
        )
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                {nav}
            </nav>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Есть компонент Auth в котором происходит авторизация

```
export default class Auth extends Component {
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var nickname = e.target.nickname.value;
    var password = e.target.password.value;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/login',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        responseType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            nickname: nickname,
            password: password
        }),
        success: data => {
            var loginErrorMsg = $('#loginErrorMsg');

            if (data.error) {
                loginErrorMsg.text(data.error).removeClass('hidden')
                return
            }

            loginErrorMsg.addClass('hidden');
            browserHistory.push('/')
        }
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <h3>Welcome to LangEx!</h3>
                <h3>You can to chat here in foreign languages with people from all world and to make new friends</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="register-form-box">
                <div className="alert alert-danger hidden" role="alert" id="loginErrorMsg"></div>
                <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control login-inp" name="nickname"
                           placeholder="Nickname"/>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control login-inp" name="password"
                           placeholder="Password"/>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Log in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

index.js

```
render(
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path='home' component={Home}/>
        <Route path='users' component={Users}/>
        <Route path='user/:id' component={Profile}/>
        <Route path='chat' component={Chat}/>
        <Route path='auth' component={Auth}/>
        <Route path='logout' component={Logout}/>
        <Route path='registration' component={Registration}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' component={NotFound}/>
</Router>,
document.getElementById('root')
```

)

Сама задача, если пользователь успешно авторизовался в App, то нужно обновить меню, которое отображает компонент App. Как это сделать, как через один компонент обновить render другого? Я делал так, в App в componentWillReceiveProps() отправлял запрос на сервер и смотрел, авторизован ли пользователь или нет, если авторизован, то менял state в App и render отрисовывал нужное меню. Такой подход наверное не совсем правильный? Подскажите, как правильнее решить задачу

Answer (score 1):

Задачу не трудно решить с использованием Redux для хранения глобального стейта приложения, где будет храниться информация о пользователе и его логине. Так же это можно будет использовать, чтобы перенаправлять пользователя на страницу входа.